Why did Drax say, "Every single time"?
Mantis manipulates Bletelsnort’s mind, which makes Bletelsnort
flirt with Drax:

Bletelsnort: What was... What was your name again?
Drax: Drax the Destroyer.
Bletelsnort: That is such a lovely name. I'll get the door for you.
I'll be here when you come back out, okay?
Drax: Sure. Every single time.

Why did Drax say, "Every single time"?

Drax is becoming annoyed about the fact that Mantis keeps abusing her powers, making people fall hopelessly in love with things.
We learn that she did it off-screen (before the film started):

Mantis: It is wrong to manipulate the feelings of friends.
Drax: What about that time you made me fall in love with my sock?
Mantis: Well, that was funny.

And she used her powers to abduct Kevin Bacon during the Guardians of the Galaxy: Holiday Special



